# what is admin jwt secret in strapi v3

Tags: node.js, strapi

When ever I create a strapi environment with npx create-strapi-app The server.js file in config folder has this admin jwt secret environment variable what is it used for

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', 'dfee1c43fb8d2e506ad627'),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.admin.auth.secret` used in JWT token creation during admin authorization process

earlier 3.1 secret for admin part generated automatically, but since 3.1 it should be part of config. Please, check [migration guide](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-3.0.x-to-3.1.x.html#_2-define-the-admin-jwt-token).

Let's check source code [authentication.js](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/core/admin/server/controllers/authentication.js#L45)
We can see that `createJwtToken` used for token creation for admin part.
Definition here [services/token.js](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/core/admin/server/services/token.js#L30)
It refer to

```js
const getTokenOptions = () => {
  const { options, secret } = strapi.config.get('server.admin.auth', {});

  return {
    secret,
    options: _.merge(defaultJwtOptions, options),
  };
};
```

and here you can see that `secret` from `server.js`  used for JWT creation. `server.js` config propose to use environment variable with `ADMIN_` prefix to identify that it's admin part related and separated from JWT for API